# Django Queryset is not iterable

Tags: python, django

Right now i am trying to pull all of the objects out of my database and display them onto a web page using django and PostgreSQL, the syntax is slightly different due to the use of the Django Mako Plus framework, but the underlying code is the same. The only major difference is that in the template the syntax is changed from `{{code here}}` to `${code here}`.

Here is my view:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django_mako_plus import view_function
from datetime import datetime
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django import forms
from homepage import models as cmod
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.shortcuts import render
from homepage.models import User
# from homepage.models import 
from homepage.models import DReferForm
import random, string

@view_function
def process_request(request):
    dReferral = DReferForm.objects.all()

    context = {
        'dReferral':dReferral,
    }
    # The DMP Equivalent when rendering the page
    return request.dmp.render('submissions.html', context)
```

Here is my template:

```
<%inherit file="base.htm" />

<%block name="content">

<h1>Testing</h1>

%for i in dRefferal:
    <p>Doctor Name: ${i.Fname}</p>
%endfor

</%block>
```

Whenever I try to load the webpage, I get an object not iterable error.

If I use this exact same code on any other model it works just fine and pulls all the data.

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Please post the full traceback. This furthermore does not look like Django (perhaps jinja?)

Comment: You have a typo in the template - `dRefferal` for `dReferral` - but without seeing the traceback it's impossible to know if that is the cause of the error.

Comment: @DanielRoseman The issue was the typo ;_;  If you post that as the answer I'll accept it.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in the template - `dRefferal` for `dReferral`.